# SQLAlchemy - insert > 1M rows - process killed

Tags: python, memory-management, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using the following bit of code to insert over 1M of entries in an SQL table (the ItemOrderType bit is because I think I made an error when writing the entries from another source using the SQLAlchemy's decl enum recipe...)

```
def run_import():
    with open('listings.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=";")
        inserts = []
        for row in reader:
            inserts.append({'item_id': int(row[0]),
                            'order_type': ItemOrderType.from_string(row[1].replace('<','').replace('>','')),
                            'listings': int(row[2]),
                            'unit_price': int(row[3]),
                            'quantity': int(row[4])})

            if len(inserts) == 10000:
                db.engine.execute(ItemOrder.__table__.insert(), inserts)
                inserts = []
        db.engine.execute(ItemOrder.__table__.insert(), inserts)
```

Either way, without the len(inserts) trick, the insert won't even happen, the process just returns a message "Killed". With it, I get to about 750k records before it is killed.

When monitoring the process in top, I see that the VIRT memory is rising to about 1200m before it's killed, res stays at around 230m.

Is this a leak in sqlalchemy? I would assume that after the engine executes the inserts, any  memory that was used is release?

This is the python version I'm using on Archlinux:
Python 2.7.6 (default, May 26 2014, 10:25:14) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved it myself. I did not mention that I was running flask to connect with sqlalchemy, and flask itself was running in debug mode, which seems to hold on to data, causing the memory to run out.